# how can I use d3 to display a div at a fixed position over an svg?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 implementation which displays hover panels over elements on user mouseover. I have a new requirement to display a summary panel of the same style towards the lower right-hand corner of the svg.  Here's the d3 code that I use to display the onmouseover hover panels:

```
d3.select('UnitedStatesTotalPanel')
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
```

Is it possible to adapt this code to display a div over the svg in a fixed position?  The problem is that the code above is based on the occurence of an event so it seems that this code will need to be adapted or changed to accomodate a one-time display of a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) to get the position of your SVG, and then set the position of your div accordingly.

The problem is that SVGs don't support offsetTop/offsetLeft, so, you'll have to wrap your SVG in a `<div>`.

To show the div independent of the `mouseover` event just append it, as any other regular element.

Check this demo:

```js
var svgPosition = document.getElementById("mySvg");

var div = d3.select("body")
 .append("div")
 .attr("class", "fixedDiv");
 
div.html("This is a fixed div<br>based on SVG position")
 .style("top", svgPosition.offsetTop + 90 + "px")
 .style("left", svgPosition.offsetLeft + 10 + "px");
```

```css
svg {
    background-color: tan;
}

.fixedDiv {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left; padding:4px;">Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet</div>
<div style="overflow:hidden;" id="mySvg">
 <svg ></svg>
</div>
```